# Create a read-only MySQL user and allow that user to get into server using SSH

Tags: 14.04, ssh, mysql

At my company we have a server that hosts data for a customer in MySQL. Now the customer wish to gain read access to the data.
However it's only possible to connect to the MySQL database through the SSH tunnel.
Now I am wondering if it was possible to make a read-only MySQL user together with a SSH key that only allows them access to the database.
What are my options?

Comment: Customer needs to access MySQL console by hands, or just generic MySQL API access to directly connect to database with some software?

Comment: They need to connect it to some software I think, not really sure.